# Caching Django SQL queries on foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a model which contains a foreign key to a different model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   ...
   picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
   ...
```

Im my template, I have an instance of MyModel and in three different places I access it's picture attribute this way `{{ mymodel.picture }}`.

When I open the debug_toolbar I see that three different SQL queries were made to the database. Shouldn't Django cache the first query and serve it afterwards? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, Django should cache that lookup after the first one. Something else must be going on - are you sure that you have the same `mymodel` instance each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% with picture = mymodel.picture %}

My Picture Size Large {{ picture }}
My Picture Size Medium {{ picture }}
My Picture Size Small  {{ picture }}

{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the with tag `{% with p = mymodel.picture %}...{% endwith %}`, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with